# How to create responsive rows and columns in node body

Tags: theming

Add Content > Basic Page > In body field, I would like to create four responsive rows in bootstrap theme as shown in the following image:

Tablet/laptop/desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

I started writing the below html in the body field but I could not do it. Can you please help me on how to accomplish that?

```
 <div class = "col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is best handled with views. You can use [views_bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) to generate list like that. If you don't want to use views you can add your own HTML into body field but you will need to make sure that you select input format as Full HTML OR PHP. This will ensure that your HTML elements don't get stripped off.